# Convert NFA for email validation into DFA

Tags: dfa, nfa

Can anyone help on how to convert the NFA for this email validation into a DFA?

[image: Image For Email Validation NFA]

In order to make the conversion I have first created state transition table, then can any one help to create DFA?

[image: NFA State Transition Table]

Comment: @ggorlen ok i will show you what I have done but could you please help, cuz am beginner in that thanks

Comment: @ggorlen but the problem is I CAN NOT AGAIN POST ANY update, since you showd the image, each time i try to post anything, it says you dont have enough reputation for the image you just show

Comment: @ggorlen could you please help ?

Comment: @ggorlen can you update the question and hekp me please

Comment: Sure, thanks for the attempt. Looks good. I have a question, though: how is `a-z` supposed to differentiate between `com` and a `c`? For example, the `foo@commando.com` seems like it'd fail parsing, or I don't quite follow how `com` can be a token given the apparent single-character parsing scheme.

Comment: Are you familiar with the powerset (subset) construction?

Comment: Somewhat, but I don't see how that's involved--can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Producing a DFA from your epsilon closures seems direct. Each closure forms a single DFA state, and the transitions in the DFA are the aggregation of transitions for nodes in the epsilon closure of the NFA. Here's the transition table for the DFA from your e-closures:

```
   | a-z | 0-9 | @ | _  | .  | com
---|-----|-----|---|----|----|-----
A^ | AB  |     |   |    |    |
AB | AB  | AB  | C |    |    |
C  | CD  | CD  |   | CD |    |
CD | CD  | CD  |   | CD | CE |
CE | CD  | CD  |   | CD |    | F
F$ |     |     |   |    |    |
```

Here's the DFA for this table ([view on graphviz](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20G%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rankdir%3DLR%3B%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Dpoint%5D%3B%20qi%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Ddoublecircle%5D%3B%20F%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Dcircle%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20qi%20-%3E%20A%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20A%20%20-%3E%20AB%20%5Blabel%3D%22a-z%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20AB%20-%3E%20AB%20%5Blabel%3D%22a-z%20%7C%200-9%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20AB%20-%3E%20C%20%20%5Blabel%3D%22%40%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20C%20%20-%3E%20CD%20%5Blabel%3D%22a-z%20%7C%200-9%20%7C%20_%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20CD%20-%3E%20CD%20%5Blabel%3D%22a-z%20%7C%200-9%20%7C%20_%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20CD%20-%3E%20CE%20%5Blabel%3D%22.%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20CE%20-%3E%20CD%20%5Blabel%3D%22a-z%20%7C%200-9%20%7C%20_%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20CE%20-%3E%20F%20%20%5Blabel%3D%22com%22%5D%0D%0A%7D)):

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR;
 
    node [shape=point]; qi;
    node [shape=doublecircle]; F;
    node [shape=circle];

    qi -> A;
    A  -> AB [label="a-z"]
    AB -> AB [label="a-z | 0-9"];
    AB -> C  [label="@"]
    C  -> CD [label="a-z | 0-9 | _"]
    CD -> CD [label="a-z | 0-9 | _"]
    CD -> CE [label="."]
    CE -> CD [label="a-z | 0-9 | _"]
    CE -> F  [label="com"]
}
```